# Line fitting algorithm OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, line, detection, curve-fitting

I have applied the Canny edge detection on my source image and then used the findContours function to find the longest contour. But after this, I would like to use the line fitting algorithm ( fitline function ) in OpenCV to draw a line along the sky-sea line in the source image.

Source Image:

[image: Source image]

After Canny edge detection and finding the longest contour:

[image: After Canny edge detection and finding the longest contour]

Result expected after line fitting:

[image: Result after line fitting]

Any help would be deeply appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You don't simply use Canny edge detector for horizon.

(1) Apply median filter large enough to hide small scale features.

```
cv::medianBlur( imgOriginal, blurred, 101 );
```

(2) Compute gradient magnitude. E.g. using the ugly forward difference as follows:

```
cv::Mat m;
blurred.convertTo(m,CV_32F);
cv::Mat crop = m( cv::Rect(0,0,m.cols-1,m.rows-1) );
const cv::Mat shiftx = m( cv::Rect(1,0,m.cols-1,m.rows-1) );
const cv::Mat shifty = m( cv::Rect(0,1,m.cols-1,m.rows-1) );
cv::Mat dx,dy;
cv::subtract( shiftx, crop, dx );
cv::subtract( shifty, crop, dy );
cv::pow( dx, 2.0, dx );
cv::pow( dy, 2.0, dy );
cv::add( dx, dy, dx );
m.setTo(0);
cv::sqrt( dx, crop );
```

(3) Collect points where the gradient magnitude is higher than --- say --- half the maximum.

```
cv::minMaxLoc( m, &mi, &ma );
const float thr = ma/2.0;
std::vector< cv::Point2f > pts;
for ( int y=0; y<m.rows;++y)
// ...
```

(4) And fit the line on them.

You should get quite nice fit.